# Deprecation warning regarding sass processor on upgrading to rails 4.2.7.1

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass

After upgrading from `rails 4.2.5` to `rails 4.2.7.1` I get the following deprecation warning

```
DEPRECATION WARNING: SassTemplate is deprecated please use SassProcessor instead  (called from _app_views_layouts_application_html_erb__3924964597462090847_70339025036080 at /Users/Chris/Documents/Sites/golf_mentor/app/views/layouts/application.html.erb:11
```

The relevant line of application.html.erb is

The warning also happens at other points in the code where `stylesheet_link_tag` is called, so it appears to be this tag that causes the problem rather than what is in the css.scss files.

How do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was caused by using an old version of `sassc-rails`.   Upgrading to version `1.3.0` removed the deprecation warnings.